# Function for searching an array for more than 1 condition

Tags: arrays, visual-studio, search

Ill just include the problem and my partial solution to it. This problem is from my first programming class so please be gentle.

Write a Function procedure that returns the index of a property in the propListBox when the property satisfies search conditions. This function will be called by both event handlers of Search and SearchNext Buttons later on.

Use the following procedure header. (This function will be used for implementing the requirement #12 and #13.)

The first parameter is the Index in the list of properties that the search will start from. The second parameter is the search criterion for number of bedrooms, the third for number of bathrooms, and the fourth for state. If 0 is passed as parameter for bedroom/bathroom, that means user does not specify a search criterion for bedroom/bathroom. If Nothing is passed as parameter for state, that means user does not specify a search criterion for State.

If you have multiple conditions, you should find a property that satisfies all conditions. (For example, if ‘0’ is given for the startIndex (meaning you will start the search from the first property), and if 3 is passed as parameter for bedroom and 3 is passed for bathroom, the first property that satisfies both conditions is the property with the address ‘1314 Fern Ave, Orlando, FL 32814’.

Use loop structures to go through each property and compare #of bedroom, #of bathroom and state of the property with the parameters passed to the function. Note the info about properties is stored in nbeds, nbaths, and states arrays.

The property search should start from the startIndex and should stop when the first property that satisfies all conditions is found.

This function should return the index (in propListBox) of the found property. If not found, the function returns -1.

--------------my code below------------

```
  Private Function SearchForm(ByVal startIndex As Integer, 
  ByVal bedroom As Integer, 
  ByVal bathroom As Integer, 
  ByVal propState As String) As Integer

  Dim propFound As Integer
    Dim highIndex As Integer = propListBox.Items.Count - 1

    For propIndex As Integer = propListBox.SelectedIndex To highIndex

        If nBeds(propIndex) = bedroom Or bedroom = 0 Then
            If nBaths(propIndex) = bathroom Or bathroom = 0 Then
                If states(propIndex) = propState Or propState = String.Empty Then
                    propListBox.SelectedIndex = propIndex
                End If
            End If



        Else : MsgBox("Not Found")
        End If
    Next propIndex

    Return propFound
End Function
```

Comment: How are you implementing both parts of this requirement? `The property search should start from the startIndex and should stop when the first property that satisfies all conditions is found.`  Also how are you setting and the returning the index of the match?

Comment: I'm not sure. Is the series of if statements a viable way to check these conditions? I have had a lot of trouble with arrays which is why im coming here.

Comment: Yes, I think your series of nested If statements is a good approach to finding a match.  Where is the loop starting from currently?...and is the "startIndex" parameter getting used anywhere in your code?  When you have found a match, how are you setting the "propFound" variable and stopping the loop?

Comment: is it as simple as return propFound = propindex.selectedindex?

Comment: Basically, but you would simply set it from within the loop with `propFound = propIndex`, and then use `Exit For` afterwards to get of out the loop.  Additionally, you'd need to set propFound to an initial value of -1 with `Dim propFound As Integer = -1`.

Comment: Also, your "Not found" message is in the wrong place.  You'd only want that message to appear after exiting the For loop and finding that propFound is still -1.  It would make more sense, however, to display that message where ever the return value is begin captured, and not within the function itself.